# One or more errors occurred. at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have entity-frameWork.
I wrote query that get sequence. and I got this error.
the code:

```
var rawQuery = _contextORA.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL from dual");
var task = rawQuery.SingleAsync();
int nextVal = task.Result;
return nextVal.ToString();
```

**end I get this error
Message:**

> Message One or more errors occurred.  stackTrace: at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification) InnerException :
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

**update**

I got the error in the line

```
rawQuery.SingleAsync();
```

what can I do?
On the local computer it works for me. But when I distribute it to test server - it gets the error. (and I use the same DB in the local and in the test)

Comment: Remove the irrelevant Task / Async information and concentrate on `InvalidCastException`. Apparently the result is not `int`, I would try `long`.

Comment: change to long didnt help. got the same error

Comment: You need to find the type of the column returned by the Oracle query. Try `var cn = _contextORA.Database.Connection; var cmd = cn.CreateCommand(); cmd.CommandText = "select SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL from dual"; cn.Open(); var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); var colType = dr.GetFieldType(0);` and see what's the value of the `colType` variable.